# React Native: How do I create full screen gradient background with LinearGradient in expo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

**I'm building a Login Screen in react native v0.55 using CRNA tool and I want the use gradient in the background from top to bottom completely. I tried but by this way, I can't create login screen properly. Below is my code please help me. here is the link as well*->***  https://snack.expo.io/r1aqB9gwQ

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo';

// You can import from local files

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-elements'; // Version can be specified in package.json

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <LinearGradient
      colors={["blue", "red"]}
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        height: 570,
      }} >
      <Text style={{
      justifyContent: 'center',
      textAlign: 'center',
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      }}>Hi World</Text>
      </LinearGradient>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `height: 570` to `top: 0`. Height can different for different devices.

Comment: Not Working!! when I change it to top: 0 it shows just a little gradient at the bottom. See the sample at https://snack.expo.io/ByexwSWvX

Comment: @user9824674 its `top`, not `Top`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out it worked. Also found another way by using flex:1 and position: 'relative'

Comment: Yes, that is the ideal way. you don't need to set position: 'relative'. by default its relative

Comment: I see, but justifyContent: 'center',
      textAlign: 'center',  is not working fir the text

Comment: it should be for Parent layout of <Text>, that means for style of <LinearGradient> `justifyContent: 'center'` and `alignItems:'center'`

Comment: `const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  linearGradient: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
});`
this did it for me

Answer (score 0):

```
style={{flex:1}}
```

or your main container style

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved by

> import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient'
>
> import { Container, Header, Title, Content, Button, Icon, Left, Body,
>   Right } from 'native-base'

```
<Container>
                <LinearGradient
                    colors={['#2695d9', '#2f61ad']}
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    //  Linear Gradient 
                    start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                    end={{ x: 0, y: 1 }}
                >
                    <Header transparent>
                        <Left>
                            <Button transparent>
                                <Icon name="arrow-back" />
                            </Button>
                        </Left>
                        <Body>
                            <Title>Transparent</Title>
                        </Body>
                        <Right>
                            <Button transparent>
                                <Text>Cancel</Text>
                            </Button>
                        </Right>
                    </Header>
                    <Content>
                        <Text> Header with transparent prop </Text>
                    </Content>
                </LinearGradient>

            </Container>
```